# Aplicação para dar indicações pelo gps em android?

Tags: android, gps

Estava a pensar em desenvolver uma aplicação em android para os utilizadores de autocarro/ónibus encontrarem as paragens. 
A ideia seria ter as minhas coordenadas as coordenadas da paragem e ver a distancia , mas preciso também de indicações por exemplo 30 metros para a frente 20 para a direita ou simplesmente abrir o google maps e mostrar uma linha do ponto onde eu estou ate paragem pelo caminho mais rápido , alguém sabe se o android permite fazer isso ? se sim como ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se não estou enganado, a [API de mapas do Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation) permite iniciar uma `Intent` que fornece essa navegação entre a localização atual e um ponto definido, como se fosse um navegador de GPS.

Não sei dizer se ele calcula a menor distância, porque a documentação fornece poucas informações sobre isso.

É bem simples a princípio, basta criar a `Intent` e iniciar:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);

mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

startActivity(mapIntent);
```

A documentação deixa claro que o parâmetro de `q` aceita endereços ou uma posição geográfica:

```
google.navigation:q=a+street+address
google.navigation:q=latitude,longitude
```

É claro que você irá criar uma dependência sobre o Google Maps, que pode não estar disponível no aparelho (vai saber porque...)

Mas é bom fazer a seguinte verificação antes de iniciar para não causar uma falha no app:

```
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager() != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Google Maps não está disponível!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```